# groupby , custom function uses column every first 4 rows (after grouping)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have the following dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'id':[0,1,2,3,4, 0, 1,2,3, 0, 1, 2], 
                   'val':[0.1, 0.2, 0.02, 0.52, 0.017,0.87, 0.24, 0.67, 0.9, 1.0, 0.99, 0.56]})

df

name    id  val
0   a   0   0.100
1   a   1   0.200
2   a   2   0.020
3   a   3   0.520
4   a   4   0.017
5   b   0   0.870
6   b   1   0.240
7   b   2   0.670
8   b   3   0.900
9   c   0   1.000
10  c   1   0.990
11  c   2   0.560
```

Now, I want to do this.

I want to groupby name and apply a custom function to the dataframe.

After grouping by name, I want to check the `id` column and if it contains at least 4 rows, then apply the function which calls another one (`calc`) which receives as input a numpy array which contains the 4 first id's.

For example, I want to apply the function for `name` : `a and b` since they have `id`: 0,1,2,3,4 and 0,1,2,3 . So, they both have at least 4 rows.

And I want to use the first 4 rows in order to use them as input to `calc` function.

```
def calc(p):

    return p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3]
```

Now, something like that for the custom function (it doesn't work):

```
def myfunc(data):
    if (data.id.values <=3):
        val1 = data[data.id==0].val.values
        val2 = data[data.id==1].val.values
        val3 = data[data.id==2].val.values
        val4 = data[data.id==3].val.values


    data['calc'] = calc(np.array([val1, val2, val3, val4]))
    return data
```

It gives me `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I can't find a way to count properly the `id` and fill the vals.

**Some clarification**

Regarding the calc function. I want to do more complex calculations (not the addition). The calc  function must receive as input an array with at least 4 values.

An expected output would be:

```
name    calc
a       0.84 (0.1+0.2+0.020+0.520)
b       2.68 (0.870+0.240+0.670+0.900)

or maybe something like (since it is name based):

name    id  val    calc
0   a   0   0.100  0.84
1   a   1   0.200  0.84
2   a   2   0.020  0.84
3   a   3   0.520  0.84
4   a   4   0.017  0.84
5   b   0   0.870  2.68
6   b   1   0.240  2.68
7   b   2   0.670  2.68
8   b   3   0.900  2.68
9   c   0   1.000  
10  c   1   0.990
11  c   2   0.560
```

**Update**

I changed (according to @Erfan's answer) to `groupby('name')[['val']].apply(calc).reset_index()` instead of `groupby('name')['val'].apply(list).reset_index()` and the `calc` function to :

```
def calc(data):
    p0 = np.array([data.val.values[0]])
    p1 = np.array([data.val.values[1]])
    p2 = np.array([data.val.values[2]])
    p3 = np.array([data.val.values[3]])


    data['calc'] = np.array([p0, p1, p2, p3])
    return data
```

and it works fine!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you want with your `calc` function. Do you want the sum of the first 4 values in `val`? Could you add an expected output for more clarity?

Comment: @Erfan:I added a few things, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

You can chain `groupby` three times with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df[df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('count').ge(4)]\
     .groupby('name').head(4)\
     .groupby('name', as_index=False).sum().drop('id', axis=1)
```

---

```
  name   val
0    a  0.84
1    b  2.68
```

---

**Explanation**

1. `df[df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('count').ge(4)]` returns all the rows per unique name which have 4 rows or more:

```
  name  id    val
0    a   0  0.100
1    a   1  0.200
2    a   2  0.020
3    a   3  0.520
4    a   4  0.017
5    b   0  0.870
6    b   1  0.240
7    b   2  0.670
8    b   3  0.900
```

2. Then we chain it `.head(4)` which gives us only the first 4 rows per group:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('count').ge(4)]\
     .groupby('name').head(4)

  name  id   val
0    a   0  0.10
1    a   1  0.20
2    a   2  0.02
3    a   3  0.52
5    b   0  0.87
6    b   1  0.24
7    b   2  0.67
8    b   3  0.90
```

3. Finally we get sum of the first 4 rows per group with `.sum` and drop the `id` column:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('count').ge(4)]\
     .groupby('name').head(4)\
     .groupby('name', as_index=False).sum().drop('id', axis=1)

  name   val
0    a  0.84
1    b  2.68
```

---

#### Method 2

Largely the same as first method, but then using [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x['id'].count() >= 4)\
  .groupby('name').head(4)\
  .groupby('name', as_index=False).sum().drop('id', axis=1)

  name   val
0    a  0.84
1    b  2.68
```

#### Method 3

*added after comment OP to apply custom function*

You can use `.apply(list)` to get the first 4 elements in a list which you can access:

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('name')['id'].transform('count').ge(4)]\
           .groupby('name').head(4)\
           .groupby('name')['val'].apply(list).reset_index()

  name                      val
0    a   [0.1, 0.2, 0.02, 0.52]
1    b  [0.87, 0.24, 0.67, 0.9]
```

Then if you want to sum those values:

```
df2['val'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))

0    0.84
1    2.68
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!The problem is that I want to apply a custom function after grouping/filtering.And I must be able to use `p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]` for every `name`.Not just the sum.Because i will have more complex calculations as I said.

Comment: Added another solution which might solve your problem, see _method 3_. But if I was you I would take a step back and describe your problem from the start. Because in 95% of the times, you dont need a custom function, `pandas` and `numpy` provide a lot. Seems like you're stuck in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok!I changed a few things and it works fine!Thanks!You can see my update post. (upv)

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help. Enjoy working with Python and pandas :) @George

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct, below should help you

```
grouped = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x['name'].count() > 3)

for x in grouped['name'].unique():
    subf=df[df['name']==x]
    # you are still able to use the list
    #[0.1, 0.2, 0.02, 0.52, 0.017]
    #[0.87, 0.24, 0.67, 0.9]
    a=subf['val'].tolist()
    print(sum(a))
>> output
0.8570000000000001
2.6799999999999997
```